# Getting full access token Facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post the user's OAuth token to my database, so I can read their statuses using FQL.

I thought that this would work:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

but it only returns the first portion.

I also tried this:

```
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken(APP_ID.'|'.APP_SECRET);
```

but it returns the same thing as above.

How do I get the auth token so I can store it in my database?

Comment: why do you want to store it in your database? it´s only valid for 2 hours anyway, so instead of storing it you could just read the user statuses exactly when the user gets to your app.

Comment: What is "the first portion"? User's access token doesn't have any portions, it's a solid string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After callback use:

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
```

and then call getAccessToken to get long lived tokens to store in your Database:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Hope this will help.